# Want to Delete Opportunities record whose created date is 200 days ago or more

Tags: apex, visualforce, scheduled-apex, developer, developer-org

I have written a apex class with test class both are running but my code coverage is only 66%.Please help to solve the problem.

Apex Class-

```
    global class Deleteoppotest implements Schedulable{

    global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
        deleteoppo();
    }

    public static void deleteoppo() {

        for(List<opportunity> objoppo : [SELECT Id FROM opportunity WHERE CreatedDate <= :(Date.Today() - 200) LIMIT 10])
            {
                delete objoppo;
            }    
    }
}
```

Test Class

```
    @isTest
private class Deleteoppotestcls {

    static testMethod void myUnitTest() {
        // TO DO: implement unit test



        Opportunity op = new Opportunity();
        op.Name = 'test1';
        op.StageName = 'Qualified';
        op.CloseDate = Date.Today();
        op.Description ='testingoppotestcls';
        op.Business_Type__c = 'Domestic';


        insert op;


        Deleteoppotest.deleteoppo();

    }
}
```

Comment: NEVER, .... you never put a database operation (insert/update/delete/upsert) in a loop.

Answer (score 3):

Few things to be noticed here.

1. Your DML should be outside like this and also no need to use for loop

simple DML on list

```
public static void deleteoppo() {
      delete  [SELECT Id FROM opportunity 
               WHERE CreatedDate <= :(Date.Today() - 200) 
               LIMIT 10];
}
```

2. Second, create records in test class with old created date

   ```
   Opportunity op = new Opportunity();
   op.Name = 'test1';
   op.StageName = 'Qualified';
   op.CloseDate = Date.Today();
   op.Description ='testingoppotestcls';
   op.Business_Type__c = 'Domestic';
   insert op
   Datetime dt200before = Datetime.now().addDays(-201);
   Test.setCreatedDate(op.Id, dt200before );
   ```

This will set the created date 201 before date

3. Since it is a scheduler class you can schedule the class

   ```
     Test.startTest();
     Deleteoppotest objDelOpp = new Deleteoppotest();
     System.schedule('delete opp - Monday 5AM', '0 00 05 ? * 2', objDelOpp );
     Test.stopTest();
   ```

This will cover the all the code

4. And Lastly Don't forget to add asserts to check if data is deleted or not

Answer (score 1):

Here is test class that should give 100% test coverage for a schedulable class.

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=false)
private class Deleteoppotestcls {

    @TestSetup
    public static void createTestData() {
        Opportunity op = new Opportunity();
        op.Name = 'test1';
        op.StageName = 'Qualified';
        op.CloseDate = Date.Today();
        op.Description ='testingoppotestcls';
        op.Business_Type__c = 'Domestic';
        insert op;
    }

    @IsTest
    static void shouldScheduleDeletion() {
        DateTime currTime = DateTime.now();
        Integer min = currTime.minute();
        Integer hour = currTime.hour();
        String sch;

        if(min <= 58)
            sch = '0 '+ (min + 1) + ' ' + hour + ' * * ?';
        else          
            sch = '0 0 '+ (hour + 1) + ' * * ?';

        Test.startTest();
        String jobId = system.schedule('Test Deletion ' + currTime, sch, new Deleteoppotest());        
        CronTrigger ct = [SELECT Id, CronExpression, TimesTriggered, NextFireTime FROM CronTrigger WHERE Id = :jobId];
        System.assertEquals(sch, ct.CronExpression);
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It won't though. The query only returns records that have a created date over 200 days ago. The test record that you create will not be returned in the query, and the `delete objoppo;` line of code will still not be covered.

Comment: Thanks for info. However, I tested that class in dev org and its 100% covered.

Comment: I stand corrected. I had assumed the for loop was operating over single Opportunities, but it is actually operating over lists of Opportunities. Your answer does in fact give 100% code coverage.

Comment: The code has worked